# Player animation doesn't want to stop

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation, character, game-development

Currently working on a mobile game where i need to move the character with a virtual joystick ,i used a code from a tutorial i saw on the internet, the problem is when i move the joystick the character moves in the right direction and the animation works fine but when i release it  the character doesn't stop

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem;

[RequireComponent(typeof(CharacterController))]
public class CharacterMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
private CharacterController controller;
private Vector3 playerVelocity;
private bool groundedPlayer;
private Animator animator;
private PlayerInput input;
private InputActionAsset asset;
private Transform cameraTransform;
private float playerSpeed = 2.0f;
private float gravityValue = -9.81f;
int isWalkingHash;

Vector2 currentMovement;

bool movementPressed;


private void Awake()
{
    input = new PlayerInput();

    input.CharacterControls.Move.performed += ctx =>
    {
        currentMovement = ctx.ReadValue<Vector2>();
        movementPressed = currentMovement.x != 0 || currentMovement.y != 0;
    };
}
private void Start()
{
    controller = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
    animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
    isWalkingHash = Animator.StringToHash("isWalking");
    cameraTransform = Camera.main.transform;
}

void Update()
{
    HandleMovement();
    groundedPlayer = controller.isGrounded;
    if (groundedPlayer && playerVelocity.y < 0)
    {
        playerVelocity.y = 0f;
    }

    Vector2 inputs = input.CharacterControls.Move.ReadValue<Vector2>();
    Vector3 move = new Vector3(inputs.x, 0, inputs.y);
    controller.Move(move * Time.deltaTime * playerSpeed);

    if (move != Vector3.zero)
    {
        gameObject.transform.forward = move;
    }

    playerVelocity.y += gravityValue * Time.deltaTime;
    controller.Move(playerVelocity * Time.deltaTime);
}

void HandleMovement()
{
    bool isWalking = animator.GetBool(isWalkingHash);

    if (movementPressed && !isWalking)
    {
        animator.SetBool(isWalkingHash, true);
    }

    if (!movementPressed && isWalking)
    {
        animator.SetBool(isWalkingHash, false);
    }
}

private void OnEnable()
{
    input.CharacterControls.Enable();
}

private void OnDisable()
{
    input.CharacterControls.Disable();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in the `HandleMovement()` method. First of all I don't think you even need `bool isWalking = animator.GetBool(isWalkingHash);`. Also use an `else` statement after `if (movementPressed && !isWalking) { animator.SetBool(isWalkingHash, true); }`. You don't need the 2nd `if` statement if you use `else`.

Also according to you code `isWalkingHash` is a `int` variable defined in the script and for `animator.SetBool(isWalkingHash, false);` to work you have to pass the name of the boolean parameter deined in the parameter section in the animator as a string.